# Two types of sub-enumerator

Tags: enumerate

I'm using custom enumerators for work packages and tasks:

```
\newlist{WP}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[WP,1]{label*=WP\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[WP,2]{label=Task \arabic{WPi}.\arabic{WPii}.,ref=\arabic{WPi}.\arabic*}
```

which results in the following output:

```
WP1. Foo    
   Task 1.1. Bar   
   Task 1.2. Baz
WP2. Another
   Task 2.1. Foobar
```

I'd like to be able to put another kind of sub-enumerator there, with the numbering restarting, such as:

```
WP1. Foo    
   Task 1.1. Bar   
   Task 1.2. Baz
   Deliverable 1.1. Report on Bar and Baz
WP2. Another
   Task 2.1. Foobar
   Deliverable 2.1. Report on Foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but I found a way of doing it within the enumerate itself:

```
 \begin{WP}
    \item Foo
    \begin{WP}
        \item Bar
        \item Baz
    \end{WP} 
    \begin{enumerate}[label=D\arabic{WPi}.\arabic*,ref=\arabic{WPi}.\arabic*]
       \item Report on Bar and Baz
    \end{enumerate}
 \end{WP}
```